# Filling table with weeks of the year skips first week of 2021

Tags: sql-server

So, I am using the following snippet on a procedure, which fills me a temporary table with the first day of each year's week, the week number and month name.
However, when I reach week 53, of 2020, it jumps to week 2 of 2021. This happens because the first of january is in the so called week 53 (which is correct), but it should also be creating another row with the first week of january 2021 (even with the sunday as being in 2020, as it should).

Snippet:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

DECLARE @tblSundays TABLE (
    [year] INT
    ,[month] INT
    ,[week] INT
    ,[date] DATETIME
    )

DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = '2020-12-12'
    ,@DateTo DATETIME = '2021-06-06';

--select @DateFrom,@DateTo;
WITH CTE (dt)
AS (
    SELECT @DateFrom
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, dt)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE dt < @DateTo
    )
INSERT INTO @tblSundays
SELECT datepart(year, dt)
    ,datepart(month, dt)
    ,datepart(week, dt)
    ,dt
FROM CTE
WHERE datepart("dw", dt) = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
;
select * from @tblSundays
```

Is there any way that I can do this within this snippet, or should I create a manual verification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a couple of little tricks to set week 1 to the first Sunday of the year (tested for the next 30 years):

```
set datefirst 7

declare @tblSundays table ([year] int, [month] int, [week] int, [date] date)
declare @DateFrom datetime = '20201212', @DateTo datetime = '20510112';

-- Get the next closest Sunday
select @DateFrom = dateAdd(wk, dateDiff(wk, 0, @datefrom - 1 ), 0) + 6 

with CTE (dt) as (
    select @DateFrom
    union all
    select dateAdd(dd, 7, dt) from CTE where dt < @DateTo
    )
insert into @tblSundays
select  datePart(yy, dt),
        datePart(mm, dt),
        datePart(wk, dt - (1 + (datePart(dy, dt) + 5) % 7) % 7),
        dt
from CTE
-- where datepart(dw, dt) = 1
option (maxrecursion 1600);

select *, datePart(wk, [date]) as [standard_wk]
from @tblSundays
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could have those two condition on that same snippet, but you could add a second query there to complete what you are trying to do.

Something like this, maybe:

```
SET datefirst 7 
DECLARE @tblSundays TABLE 
  ( 
     [year]  INT, 
     [month] INT, 
     [week]  INT, 
     [date]  DATETIME
  ) 
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = '2020-12-12', 
        @DateTo   DATETIME = '2021-06-06'; 

--select @DateFrom,@DateTo; 

WITH cte (dt) 
     AS (SELECT @DateFrom 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(d, 1, dt) 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  dt < @DateTo) 
INSERT INTO @tblSundays 
SELECT Datepart(year, dt), 
       Datepart(month, dt), 
       Datepart(week, dt), 
       dt
FROM   cte 
WHERE  Datepart("dw", dt) = 1 
OPTION (maxrecursion 1000); 

--second new query
WITH cte (dt) 
     AS (SELECT @DateFrom 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(d, 1, dt) 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  dt < @DateTo) 
INSERT INTO @tblSundays 
SELECT Datepart(year, dt), 
       Datepart(month, dt), 
       Datepart(week, dt), 
       dt
FROM   cte 
WHERE  Datepart("dw", dt) <> 1 
       AND Datepart(day, dt) = 1 
       AND Datepart(week, dt) NOT IN (SELECT week 
                                      FROM   @tblSundays) 
OPTION (maxrecursion 1000); 

SELECT * 
FROM   @tblSundays 
ORDER  BY year, 
          month, 
          week
```

Would that be OK?